# Model (or approximate model) of drone take-off forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, aerodynamics, aircraft

I would like to implement a model of the force/uplift the floor makes in a multicopter take-off, but I don't find any info of this exact dynamic.

Is there any paper that tackles this issue? Or any other similar approximation?

My final interest is to make a simple model, not so much as a full air particles simulation type, but any info I could get is appreciated.